# A Rails active record scope that selects models that do not have at least one nested has many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

I'm working with Spree. In Spree a `Product` has many `Variants` which has many `Images`.

I want to add a scope to the `Product` that only returns products which do not have at least one image on any of their variants. This is to help admins find products they need to put images on. I need to do it through a sql scope vs a method like `select` because the scope is applied to a collection before it goes into the [ransack search gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

Raw SQL could look like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Spree_Products AS P JOIN Spree_Variants AS V ON P.id = V.product_id LEFT JOIN Spree_Assets AS A ON V.id = A.viewable_id WHERE A.id is null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :your_scope, -> do
  where("spree_products.id IN (
    SELECT product_id FROM spree_variants WHERE (
      spree_variants.id NOT IN (
        SELECT viewable_id FROM spree_assets
      )
    )  
  )")
end
```